# What's the junior officers' uniform variant Memory Alpha mentions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-uniforms

On the [Memory Alpha page on Starfleet uniforms from the 2350s to the 2370s](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(2350s-2370s)), there is a photo of Alyssa Ogawa titled

> Sciences blue: Ogawa in a junior officers's variant

The uniform she is wearing, though, looks like a regular TNG Type B uniform as worn by all of the crew (starting with the *senior* crew/the main characters).

The only other mention of a junior officer's uniform in the entire article is that of an unusual one-time hybrid between TNG Type A and B uniforms. That one-off uniform features the type B collar and the type A piping. However, Ogawa's uniform in the aforementioned photo does not sport any such features, as far as I can see.

**What about Ogawa's uniform is specific to *junior* officers, or a *variant* of any regular uniform type?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Ogawa's uniform]

There is a visible seam down the middle front of the uniform, as with the Type A uniforms, while the other visible features conform with the Type B uniform.